# How to update/write data to google spreadsheet api android (api v4)

Tags: android, google-sheets-api

I have been working on an application where I need to write and update data to a spreadsheet using google spreadsheet api. I have followed the Android Quickstart provided by google [Google Sheets API
 Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/android#step_5_setup_the_sample) and was able to retreive data from the google spreadsheet but I am not able to understand how to write data. Please help

Answer (score 12):

If you followed the Quickstart tutorial correctly, then it you are few steps from learning how to write data.

In the code provided in the Quickstart tutorial, change the line

```
private static final String[] SCOPES = { SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY };
```

to:

```
private static final String[] SCOPES = { SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS };
```

This will grant access to write on a spreadsheet.

And instead of something like

```
ValueRange response = this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                .execute();
List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
```

you must create your own ValueRange instance, valueRange in this example, and then write:

```
this.mService.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, range, valueRange)
                    .setValueInputOption("RAW")
                    .execute();
```

Choose the ValueInputOption of your preference.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching for a concrete example and not finding it, only here I was able to get something that worked for me, with the addition that I put for beginners like me. Thanks to @[Veiga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38359519/1621848)

```
Object a1 = new Object();
a1 = "TEST Row 1 Column A";
Object b1 = new Object();
b1 = "TEST Row 1 Column B";

Object a2 = new Object();
a2 = "TEST Row 2 Column A";
Object b2 = new Object();
b2 = "TEST Row 2 Column B";

ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange();
valueRange.setValues(
        Arrays.asList(
                Arrays.asList(a1, b1),
                Arrays.asList(a2, b2)));

this.mService.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, "A1:B2", valueRange)
        .setValueInputOption("RAW")
        .execute();
```

I leave this concrete example, because other threads that I saw, throw compilation problems such as "`List<String>` is not acceptable as `List<Object>`".

But I thank those collaborators, example @k9yosh in the answer to [How to assign a value to a ValueRange variable in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46171387/1621848)
, because they were also an inspiration for me to develop a concrete solution to this case.

Comment: @KaranAhuja From the Google Spread Sheet URL, you can get the ID: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SpreadSheetId/edit#gid=

Answer (score 0):

Please try going through  [Manage List-based and Cell-based Feeds](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data) to read and modify worksheets and data in Google Sheets.

However, since you're looking for the latest, as indicated in your post's title, and since version 4 of the Google Sheets API is now available, the following references will be very helpful too:

- [Google Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/)
- [Migrate to the Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration)

Comment: I think to understand this api v4 ; I need to first understand api v3..

Comment: That's basically why I gave you [Migrate to the Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration) as one of helpful references. Differences between v3 API and v4 API are given in that documentation. :)